# Email Scheduler for Salesforce

Tags: community

Would like to have an option where in an email is send on a particular date by clicking the Date?

**Clicking the Date**  means there will be a date field called **Send email to CLient**. This will send the email to the client on the specified date.

And the Record is stored in the Activity History.

For example: If a clients birthday is on Sunday and Today is Tuesday. We will write an email today saying Happy Birthday, then click the date field on Sunday.

The email will automatically send the email on that particular Date, like Sunday. Once the client receives the email, the Email will be stored in the Activity History.

Comment: can you elaborate "by clicking the date" ?

Comment: Please read the information again

Answer (score 1):

Well, the out of the box way to implement it will be to create a workflow/ lightning process to automatically schedule sending email on a specific date to client (time based workflow actions). But

1. Currently salesforce doesn't allow emails sent via workflows to be automatically recorded as activities (refer idea : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006povAAA)
2. You'll have to use a predefined email template (Can possibly embed content from some custom fields)

Alternatively, you can store custom message in some field and create a custom apex scheduler to run daily and send email using the custom message stored for client. Scheduler will run daily and consider either today's or next day's date to send email.